# How to make CAAnimation in viewController, which presented without navigationController

Tags: ios, caanimation

In my code new viewcontroller is not pushed into the navigation controller  and is presented as the widget.

```
-(void) loadBlurWidgetsWithClass:(Class) widgetClass andXib:(NSString*) xibName options:(NSDictionary *)options completion:(void (^)(void))competionBlock
{

     [self unloadBlurWidgetsRemovingView:NO];

     self.blurViewController = [[widgetClass alloc] initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil options:options];
     [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
     [self.blurViewController.view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
     [self.view addSubview:self.blurViewController.view];
     [self.blurViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

     self.blurViewController.main = self;

     [self showBlurViewDynamic:[options[@"dynamic"] boolValue] WithCompletion:^{
     for(UIView* v in self.blurViewController.view.subviews)
     {
          [_blurView addSubview:v];
     }
     if (competionBlock) {
          competionBlock();
     }
}];
```

}

And by this in new class viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear isn't fired. But in class I want to use animations, that I have to initialise in viewDidAppear. Have you a solution how I can call viewDidAppear or how I should make animation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should call that view controller's didMoveToParentViewController: method, with presenting view controller as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

u need to add `self.blurViewController's` view as subview not its subview,
in order to call `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` view controllers view should be there, but u are doing `[self.blurViewController.view removeFromSuperview];` this line removes the view controllers view there is no view in the view controller in order to call will/did appear methods. if u want to call these methods don't remove the main view of the view controller, if u don't want main view controller's view then u can set its background color to clear or alpha to zero or slightly above zero.

```
 self.blurViewController = [[widgetClass alloc] initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil options:options];
 [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
 [self.blurViewController.view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
 [self.view addSubview:self.blurViewController.view];
// [self.blurViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
 [self.blurViewController.view.alpha = 0.2f;
 //or
 //self.blurViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self showBlurViewDynamic:[options[@"dynamic"] boolValue] WithCompletion:^{
      [_blurView addSubview:self.blurViewController.view];
      if (competionBlock) {
      competionBlock();
 }}];
```

Comment: These decided my problem by calling will/did appear, but in this case I have another problem, [self.blurViewController.view removeFromSuperview];   should were present. I founded another solution to call appears function using beginAppearanceTransition and endAppearanceTransition. It's work but I don't know where calls this functions.

Comment: there method u don't need to call, system will be called,  u just need to implement these methods

Comment: "Declaration
- (void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing
                         animated:(BOOL)animated
YES if the child view controller's view is about to be added to the view hierarchy, NO if it is being removed.
If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that its views are about to appear or disappear. Do not invoke viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidAppear:, or viewDidDisappear: directly." And it's not there means that "viewDidLoad" is called, when calls "beginAppearanceTransition"?

Comment: "If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that its views are about to appear or disappear. Do not invoke viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidAppear:, or viewDidDisappear: directly." it says u don't need to call did/will appear methods, it will be called automatically by the viewcontroller, and also `viewDidload` method is called by the view controller to setup all the views that u r added to view controller.Only after viewDidLoad method u can access to all other subviews, this goes to all the view r initialised and are ready to display